# i can't add html tag in ReactDOM render file in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const data = < h1 > hello world! < /h1>
ReactDOM.render(data,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Today I wanted to work on reactjs but I had a problem that when I save that code in vs code after the code changes, it puts extra spaces between them in the html tag which causes a bug. I wanted to know if any of you had this problem and could have a problem Thank you for helping me solve it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The render method does not require a component. A element like you have will work too.

This is a common problem in VS Code Studio typically due to editor settings or extensions.

See a few answers for potential solutions:

- [eslint/prettier adding unwanted space into html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155699/eslint-prettier-adding-unwanted-space-into-html-tags)
- [VSCODE inserting spaces via format on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817613/vscode-inserting-spaces-via-format-on-save)
- [VSCode adds spaces inside HTML tags inside React code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979939/vscode-adds-spaces-inside-html-tags-inside-react-code)

Comment: Thanks.
The first link helped as if the problem was the html / css / js formatter